# convergence of $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ { (-1) }^{ n+1 }\frac { n }{ { n }^{ 2 }+a^{ 2 } } } $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following question:

For which $a\in\mathbb R$ does $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { (-1) }^{ n+1 }\frac { n }{ { n }^{ 2 }+a^{ 2 } }  } $ converge.

My answer is for all $a\in\mathbb R$, since there's some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that after it $b_n={ \frac { n }{ { n }^{ 2 }+a^{ 2 } }  } $ is monotonously decreasing to $0$, which makes it a Leibnitz series (from some point).

Is anything wrong with this claim?
(somehow it seams a bit too simple)

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Need to prove the claim that after a while, indeed when $n\gt |a|$, the terms are monotonically decreasing, but that is not hard.

Comment: Great. Thanks André.

Comment: You are welcome, you used the right tool well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your point is correct, though perhaps you should show why or when it is true:

$$a_n:=\frac n{n^2+a^2}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+a^2}\cdot\frac{n^2+a^2} n\le 1\iff$$

$$\iff \color{red}{n^3}+n^2+\color{blue}{a^2n}+a^2\le \color{red}{n^3}+2n^2+\color{blue}{a^2n}+n\iff a^2\le n^2+n$$

Now it is enough to remark that the last inequality is true *eventually* for, say $\;n\ge |a|\;$